# Apollo GraphQL responce body

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo

I'm using Apollo GraphQL for API response. Added ApolloInterceptor. The problem is that response is always nil when I try to print it to get response body, even when request is successful.

```
class CustomInterceptor: ApolloInterceptor {

    func interceptAsync<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(
        chain: RequestChain,
        request: HTTPRequest<Operation>,
        response: HTTPResponse<Operation>?,
        completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<GraphQLResult<Operation.Data>, Error>) -> Void) {
            let accessToken = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken")
            request.addHeader(name: "Authorization", value: accessToken ?? "")
            
            print(accessToken)
            print("request :\(request)")
            print("response :\(String(describing: response))")
            
            chain.proceedAsync(request: request,
                               response: response,
                               completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple default interceptors with Apollo.  They are executed in a specific order.

If you have added your interceptor *early* in the interceptor stack, it is intercepting the request before the request has been made (so the response will be nil).  If you add your interceptor *late* in the interceptor stack, the response should be non-nil (however, it will be too late to add your access token as a header by this point).

Specifically, in order for the response to have a chance to be filled in, you need to add your interceptor *after* the default `NetworkFetchInterceptor` which is what actually does the request in default Apollo.